# Using a keyword as member name in F#

Tags: f#

Does F# allow defining a member with the name of a keyword?

```
type Fruit =
  val type : string
```

in C# this is possible using @:

```
class Fruit 
{
    string @type;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double-backticks:

```
type Fruit =
    val ``type`` : string
```

Comment: note that this also allows you to have other odd names, for example ``names with spaces`` or ``names.with.dots``.

Comment: odd names cause troubles when they appear in the public api used from other languages.